# VSCodeでの言語別の設定を詳細に(特に行コメントアウト記号について)知りたい

Tags: vscode

こんにちは。
検索しても出てこなかったので、かなり強烈にVSCodeを使っていらっしゃる方にご質問です。

自分のやりたいことは、プレーンテキストの設定のときに
コメントアウト記号として、"> "
という文字を設定したいのですが、この方法がわかりません。

標準では、
Batchファイルだったりすると、"REM "になり、
JavaScriptでは、"// "となります。

プレーンテキストだと、行コメントアウト記号が設定されていないためなのか
行コメントアウト自体ができなくなっています。

繰り返しになりますが
この部分の設定を変更して、プレーンテキストなら
行コメントアウトは、"> "で、やりたいということです。

ご存知の方、おられましたら、よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[環境]
Windows 10
vscode 1.22.2

例えば、拡張機能の「Txt Syntax」をインストールした後、「txt.language-configuration.json」ファイルの「#」を「>」に変更するとできるので、この拡張機能の中を理解して、下記で作るとできるかも。
[拡張機能の作り方らしい](https://vscode-doc-jp.github.io/docs/extensions/overview.html)

Comment: できました！

Windowsだと、
"C:\Users\<ユーザー名>\.vscode\extensions\xshrim.txt-syntax-0.0.3\txt.language-configuration.json"
このファイルを次のように編集すればできました。

`
    {
        "comments": {
            "lineComment": ">",
`

とりあえず、自分で拡張機能をつくらなくても、なんとかなり、すごく助かりました。ありがとうございます。